# Entity Framework - Child object is null in GetHashCode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

EntityFramework6
MVC5

I'm new to EF and MVC and I have the scenario where I have a class that overrides Equals and GetHashCode:

EF code:

```
public partial class ProdCategory
{
    public long ProdID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public bool PermanentlyDelete { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

My Code:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null | (!object.ReferenceEquals(this.GetType(), obj.GetType())))
        {
            return false;
        }

        ProdCategory p = (ProdCategory)obj;

        if (this.Category == p.Category && this.Product == p.Product)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {                
            var result = 0;
            result = (result * 397).GetHashCode() ^ this.Product.GetHashCode();
            result = (result * 397).GetHashCode() ^ this.Category.GetHashCode();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

This class becomes a child object of a product and when I go to the list of products view the GetHashCode errors out with

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Heisenberg.dll but was not handled in user code

I thought it may be a lazy loading issue but the Product object exists in the GetHashCode function, so I'd assume if thats there, the Category should be..? I tried to force the loading of the prodCategory using:

```
var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.ProdCategories);
```

but it made no difference. So then I though I need to force the loading of the Category within the ProdCategory but I couldn't work out the syntax for this.

As a test, I commented out the GetHashCode function - the page loads OK, I can go to the details view of a product and view the prodCategory details, so it does get populated at some point. And this is what has thrown me! not sure what else to try?

I'm hoping someone can see where I'm going wrong.

UPDATE:
If I set a breakpoint in the GetHashCode - the first time it hits it, Product is populated, Category is null. If I do not run the Category line and continue, the break point is hit a second time. This time both product and category are populated.

Can anyone shed some light on whats happening and what the bst course of action is? I could do a check for if null in the GetHashCode but it really should never he null and I'd just be hiding the error.

Comment: What does `ProdCategory` do? It looks like its just an association, in which case, it should not exist in your domain model.

Comment: It contains other properties such as MarkForDeletion

Comment: First question is: why do you need the Hashcode? You can only use it for objects in memory, not in LINQ queries against the database, while I think that it's in LINQ queries where you'll do sorting and comparing.

Comment: Hi, I'm moving all this code from a winforms project. When creating the overridden equals in that project I was told that you should always change the GetHasCode function to match, as "Equal" objects should always have the same hashcode.

Comment: Well, then the question reverts to: why do you need to override Equals? Is there any code that explicitly or implicitly needs to compare `ProdCategory` instances (implicit use is, for instance, having a `Dictionary<ProdCategory,ValueType>>`).

Comment: I have implemented an Add function, which adds a ProdCategory to a list within Product. That function checks that the list doesn't already contain this ProdCategory - this is where I use the Equals function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyways, you should do your `GetHashCode` based on the foreign keys.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {                
        var result = this.ProdID.GetHashCode();
        result = (result * 397) ^ this.CategoryID;
        return result;
    }
}
```

The foreign id will never be not set (assuming that the item was "gotten" from the database) this is because the foreign ids are ON the row itself (so no join is needed). To get around the problem of the HashCode being wrong when you first instanciate the object I would do this.

```
public partial class ProdCategory
{
    protected ProdCategory() {} //protected default constructor is required by EF

    public ProdCategory(Category category, Product product)
    {
        this.Category = category;
        this.Product = product;
        this.ProdID = product.Id;
        this.CategoryID = category.Id;
    }

    public long ProdID { get; protected set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; protected set; }
    public bool PermanentlyDelete { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; protected set; }
}
```

Comment: OK - perhaps this is the better way to code the GetHashCode function (what are the reasons this is better?) but it still wouldn't explain why Category isn't populated initially. It would just be hiding the fact as the ID would be 0. in my model 0 isn't a valid value.

Comment: @Rick The reason why the Category/Product isn't populated is because you are using an actual `ProdCategory` rather than a EF proxy of a `ProdCategory`. So EF hasn't been able to inject the Lazy Loading code into the virtual property getters. Overall, relying on Lazy Loading causes more problems than it really solves.

Comment: Also, using a `GetHashCode` function that might involve a roundtrip to the database is just not very wise (`GetHashCode` is supposed to be as performant as possible, that's its whole point). I'd also not define `GetHashCode` using very-likely-mutable data (like foreign key ids)... I'd keep it at `ProdID` only unless both `ProdID` and `CategoryID` are primary keys... then again, that design doesn't make sense to me (why doesn't every product have its own id, independent of the category?)

Comment: Oh, I saw this is an association table... then it might make sense to use both `ProdID` and `CategoryID`... but just having that association table doesn't make a lot of sense... what properties does it have that would be needed? Why would you "mark for delete an association"? And if that's the case, you could do this either in `Product` or in `Category`, by just setting the association to `Category` or `Product` to null. One of the points of using an ORM is that you get rid of these "boilerplating" tables.

Comment: @Jcl Its a `.HashCode()` implementation. It could `return 0;` and still work perfectly fine (but poorly performing). This should work.

Comment: @Aron oh yes, was not really commenting on your answer, which is spot-on for the question (and I'm going to upvote right now)... just questioning the design decisions of the OP.

Comment: @Jcl I made the same observations in the OP comments. But the OP really wants to pollute his Domain with Database logic. Honestly in my opinion soft delete is an unforgivable antipattern. It reduces performance, pollutes the database schema, breaks referential integrity tests, and gives almost zero benefit. If you really need to make it easy to "undelete" use an ACTUAL database auditing solution. The soft delete doesn't help you find what needs to be undeleted.

Comment: I'm not against soft-delete... I use it myself, just automatically (I have implemented measures that upon `SaveChanges` converts marked deleted entries in the `DbSet` where the type implements `ISoftDeletableEntity` to a soft-deletion), and *also* do automatic database auditing. I just don't use soft-deletion in my logic... or have association tables in my domain, I let EF do that work for me :-)

Comment: No, it won't, but again, I don't use it for undoing, so I don't care. I store all changes  also, if I ever needed to do that. Basically, I use soft-deletion to avoid storing the whole state of the entity when it was deleted (i could do that, but I chose not-to). What really kills me is the need of storing the foreign key IDs in my POCOs (change tracking in EF using only navigation properties is hellish), but that's another point to a completely different question ;-)

Comment: Great comments guy - maybe I will rethink this part of the system. The MarkForDeletion is actually probably a bad example, it's meant to allow a category to still be assigned to a product but not currently used. e.g. you could see that a product had Category X previously but now it doesn't.(Better name = "Active"?)
A better example would be "Priority". E.g. A product has 10 categories but we can only use one at a time - so they will have a priority of 1 - 10 for example. But another product may have the same Categories but ranked differently.

Comment: @Aron Thanks for pointing out the obvious about the IDs not being 0. - that's a sicere thanks, even though it may sound sarcastic. I'm moving this code from a WPF app so orginally I never had the ID properties - only the objects, and they weren't lazy loaded. Now you've pointed this out I will definitely use the IDs and this resolves the issue I had, and like you say, it won't be calling the DB when getHashCode is called.

Comment: @Rick fair points. I fail to see why you'd need to define your own `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in such a class then (would you ever need to query this outside EF?). Are these properties that would only make sense to query from the category, and not from the product? Would it be better for these entities to have their own ID or be complex props instead of relying on prodid+categoryid as their PK and have them only as navigation properties? I don't know the answers to these questions, but if using EF you should avoid thinking in database-terms and begin thinking what would make sense as objects.

Comment: (otherwise, Aaron's answer is spot on)

Comment: @Jcl I think you may be right - I'm still getting used to EF so perhaps I'm doing things I don't need to/I shouldn't be doing. I guess I'm possibly stuck in the wrong mindset. moving to EF and MVC is quite a big learning curve. I just need to take on board the tips and criticisms from you guys who have more experience than me.